Noise on a sphere maps differently in shader editor and geometry nodes -- The previous solution on this site doesn't seem to work?
First off - I'm just starting to get into blender so I may not have the intuition / experience as many of the folks on here.
I'm trying to make a tiny planet (made from subdivided cube) where I can instance trees and buildings across certain regions of noise.  However, the problem arises in that noise is mapped differently in the shader editor and the geometry nodes.  I'm using face extrusion to easily identify the geometry node noise versus the colored noise from the shader nodes.  The color ranges in both editors are the same and so are the noise settings.
Here are my nodes (1st geometry 2nd shader):


My output is close to the result I want but for some reason not exact using the previous method (as I understand it) from this website.
Previous method here:
Basic Noise Texture maps differently in Geometry Nodes vs Shader Editor
Oddly the Higher the scale for the noise, the less accurate the mapping becomes.  I'm really not sure what's happening here!
Here's my result:


Any help would be much appreciated!

Instead of using two noises, use geometry nodes for extrusion and add a "set material" node with the "selection" taken from the "top" of the extrusion.
This way you have one material for the land, another for the water.
You can also use the "side" selection for setting material for the coast.

If the method above gives you too hard edges, you can try to "store named attribute" to the "top" selection (on point domain), and use those with an "Attribute" node in the shader. There will be a gradient from water to land.

Hint: you only need a 4d noise if you want to animate, otherwise you're fine with a 3d noise (better performance)

Ah, with some tinkering I finally put this together.  Because I'm using a cube, the instancing occurs on the noise of a cube, and stays when the cube is transformed into a sphere via subdivisions.  Plugging a sphere of equal size into the bounding box as opposed to the cube results in the instancing of points around the cube surface as if it were a sphere.
